# Thoughts on Vaccine Security

Tags: physical, physical-access, locks

Are there any recommendations for the physical security of COVID-19 vaccine?

I recently watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoqMA9vAOrQ on covid-19 vaccine distribution.  At the 0:40 mark, someone enters a code to access a locked freezer.

From a security point of view, was it a good idea or a bad idea to include this in the video?  It seems a determined hacker could carefully study the video and determine the code.

I hope they changed the code after making the video.

Comment: It's all about the value of what's at the other end. Assume they manage to make their way to the vault, steal the vaccine, then what?
1st off depending on which one it is, they'll need to potentially store it at -70.
There's also the topic of administering the vaccine, which not everyone will be an expert on. 
In most places the vaccine will be free, so why work so hard to steal something you'll get at some point anyway?

Sure, with the video someone could do some research and access it, but the likelihood of someone doing this is potentially low to non-issue.

Comment: @sir_k it might be distributed at no cost to the recipient, but it is far from valueless.  (1) the government spent a lot of money acquiring the vaccine (2) if you get COVID-19 between now and your scheduled vaccination you could die ... how much money would you pay to get it now?

Comment: I'm confused about what you are really asking. Are you asking about what the owner of ***this*** safe should do after filming, or are you asking about operational security around safes, or the value of securing vaccines?

Comment: The video only showed two digits being entered, which is surely not the entire safe combination, and it showed them from an oblique angle, such that the numbers themselves were not shown.  The last digit may have been the Enter key, as well.  I think the video presents a very, very low level of risk to the security of that safe.